# How I can use docker-registry with login/password?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have my docker-registry in localhost and I can pull/push with command: `docker push localhost:5000/someimage`
How I can push it with command like `docker push username@password:localhost:5000/someimage`?

Answer (score 37):

This solution worked for me:
First I've created a folder registry from in which I wanted to work:

```
$ mkdir registry
$ cd registry/
```

Now I create my folder in which I wil store my credentials

```
$ mkdir auth
```

Now I will create a htpasswd file with the help of a docker container.
This htpasswd file will contain my credentials and my encrypted passwd.

```
$ docker run --entrypoint htpasswd registry:2 -Bbn myuser mypassword > auth/htpasswd
```

To verify

```
$ cat auth/htpasswd
myuser:$2y$05$8IpPEG94/u.gX4Hn9zDU3.6vru2rHJSehPEZfD1yyxHu.ABc2QhSa
```

Credentials are fine. Now I have to add my credentials to my registry. Here for I will mount my auth directory inside my container:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry_private  -v `pwd`/auth:/auth  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd"  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm"  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd"  registry:2
```

TEST:

```
$ docker push localhost:5000/busybox
The push refers to a repository [localhost:5000/busybox]
8ac8bfaff55a: Image push failed
unauthorized: authentication required
```

authenticate

```
$ docker login localhost:5000
Username (): myuser
Password:
Login Succeeded
```

Retry the push

```
$ docker push localhost:5000/busybox
The push refers to a repository [localhost:5000/busybox]
8ac8bfaff55a: Pushed
latest: digest: sha256:1359608115b94599e5641638bac5aef1ddfaa79bb96057ebf41ebc8d33acf8a7 size: 527
```

Credentials are saved in ~/.docker/config.json:

```
cat ~/.docker/config.json

{
    "auths": {
        "localhost:5000": {
            "auth": "bXl1c2VyOm15cGFzc3dvcmQ="
        }
    }
```

Don't forget it's recommended to use https when you use credentials.

Here is a blog on how to use TLS (self signed certs with this approach): https://medium.com/@lvthillo/deploy-a-docker-registry-using-tls-and-htpasswd-56dd57a1215a

Comment: Getting `Error response from daemon: Get https://10.10.10.50:5000/v1/users/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client` on docker login :(

Comment: @loostro what docker version are you using? maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38695515/can-not-pull-push-images-after-update-docker-to-1-12

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: @loostro, It is because the registry that you created is with HTTP endpoint. By default it expects HTTPS. The solution is to enable access by configuring it as insecure registry. {
    "insecure-registries" : [ "hostname.registry:5000" ]
}

Comment: FYI config options are documented in https://github.com/distribution/distribution/blob/main/docs/configuration.md

Comment: registry:2 does not have  htpasswd ,seems like httpd:2

Comment: Good answer, but docker command currently gives:
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "htpasswd": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

Adapt the command a bit:
docker run --entrypoint htpasswd registry:2.7.0 -Bbn myuser mypassword > auth/htpasswd

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62531540/954701

Comment: registry:2.2 through 2.6 have htpasswd (and maybe 2.1).  I don't know why it has come and gone.

Answer (score 2):

try to set this in your docker conf file `~/.docker/config.json`

```
{
        "auths": {
                "https://localhost:5000/someimage": {
                        "auth": "username",
                        "email": "password"
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When pushing containers or if your containers are loaded within a docker-compose file from a private docker repo you can use the docker login command beforehand.

```sh
docker login -u user -p password private.repository:5000
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/