# Can not pull/push images after update docker to 1.12

Tags: docker, registry, docker-registry

The private registry was worked well based on docker 1.10.3,but I can not pull/push images after the docker updated to 1.12.0.

I had modified the /etc/sysconfig/docker as:

```
OPTIONS='--selinux-enabled=true --insecure-registry=myip:5000'
```

or

```
OPTIONS='--selinux-enabled=true --insecure-registry myip:5000'
```

but when I exec pull/push,I got this error:

```
$ docker pull myip:5000/cadvisor
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://myip:5000/v1/_ping: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

when I change back docker to 1.10.3, it still work well as below:

```
$ docker pull myip:5000/cadvisor
Using default tag: latest
Trying to pull repository myip:5000/cadvisor ... 
latest: Pulling from myip:5000/cadvisor
09d0220f4043: Pull complete 
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete 
151807d34af9: Pull complete 
14cd28dce332: Pull complete     
Digest:
sha256:33b6475cd5b7646b3748097af1224de3eee3ba7cf5105524d95c0cf135f59b47
Status: Downloaded newer image for myip/cadvisor:latest
```

Some relative information are listed below:

```
docker version
Client:
Version: 1.12.0
API version: 1.24
Go version: go1.6.3
Git commit: 8eab29e
Built:

OS/Arch: linux/amd64

Server:
Version: 1.12.0
API version: 1.24
Go version: go1.6.3
Git commit: 8eab29e
Built:

OS/Arch: linux/amd64

docker info
Containers: 4
Running: 1
Paused: 0
Stopped: 3
Images: 241
Server Version: 1.12.0
Storage Driver: devicemapper
Pool Name: docker-253:0-6809-pool
Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
Base Device Size: 107.4 GB
Backing Filesystem: xfs
Data file: /dev/loop0
Metadata file: /dev/loop1
Data Space Used: 5.459 GB
Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
Data Space Available: 34.74 GB
Metadata Space Used: 9.912 MB
Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
Metadata Space Available: 2.138 GB
Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74 GB
Udev Sync Supported: true
Deferred Removal Enabled: false
Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Use '--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev' to specify a custom block storage device.
Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
Library Version: 1.02.107-RHEL7 (2016-06-09)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
Volume: local
Network: host overlay null bridge
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: seccomp
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 24
Total Memory: 62.39 GiB
Name: server_3
ID: TITS:BL4B:M5FE:CIRO:5SW6:TVIV:HW36:J7OS:WLHF:46T6:2RBA:WCNV
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
File Descriptors: 21
Goroutines: 32
System Time: 2016-08-02T10:33:06.414048675+08:00
EventsListeners: 0
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
Insecure Registries:
127.0.0.0/8

docker exec <registry-container> registry -version
registry github.com/docker/distribution v2.2.1
```

After I restart the docker daemon in debug mode, the daemon logs when reproducing my problem are listed below:

```
DEBU[0794] Calling POST /v1.24/images/create?fromImage=10.10.10.40%3A5000%2Fcadvisor&tag=latest 
DEBU[0794] hostDir: /etc/docker/certs.d/10.10.10.40:5000 
DEBU[0794] hostDir: /etc/docker/certs.d/10.10.10.40:5000 
DEBU[0794] Trying to pull 10.10.10.40:5000/cadvisor from https://10.10.10.40:5000 v2 
WARN[0794] Error getting v2 registry: Get https://10.10.10.40:5000/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client 
ERRO[0794] Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get https://10.10.10.40:5000/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
DEBU[0794] Trying to pull 10.10.10.40:5000/cadvisor from https://10.10.10.40:5000 v1 
DEBU[0794] hostDir: /etc/docker/certs.d/10.10.10.40:5000
DEBU[0794] attempting v1 ping for registry endpoint https://10.10.10.40:5000/v1/
DEBU[0794] Fallback from error: Get https://10.10.10.40:5000/v1/_ping: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client 
ERRO[0794] Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get https://10.10.10.40:5000/v1/_ping: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
ERRO[0794] Handler for POST /v1.24/images/create returned error: Get https://10.10.10.40:5000/v1/_ping: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client 
DEBU[1201] clean 2 unused exec commands
```

What's more, I just run a simple command to launch the private registry for test, anything else is by default:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry -v 'pwd'/data:/var/lib/registry registry:2
```

No proxy is configured. In summary, it is only a quiet sample environment for test.

Comment: well, i too face the same error, but the strange thing is that i donot have /etc/sysconfig/docker file in RHEL 7, do you know any similar file that i can find ? what are the contents of this docker file? Thank you.

Comment: This file includes some options if you want to change the way the docker daemon runs. I don't know exact path in RHEL7 .But if you exec with the command "$sudo locate docker", you will find the file in somewhere

Comment: I ended up deleting the /etc/docker/daemon.json and restarting the docker service, it looks like it was overriding what was setup in /etc/sysconfig/docker

Comment: For MacOS users see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39492340/706521

Answer (score 231, accepted):

I had the same issue.

## This helped for me:

- Create  or modify */etc/docker/daemon.json* **on the client machine**

  `{ "insecure-registries":["myregistry.example.com:5000"] }`
- Restart docker daemon

  `sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart`

Comment: In my case I use Ubuntu 16.04 and /etc/default/docker (where my config was) is specific to upstart. 16.04 uses systemd. /etc/docker/daemon.json is platform-independent configuration. https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23512 https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23228

Comment: Here is the documentation how to setup insecure registry 

https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/

Comment: Create `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file if not present. Specific to `Ubuntu 16.04`

Comment: Anyone have any info for MacOS?

Comment: this helped me when I installed docker V17.x. It somehow didn't work when I had docker.io v1.x

Comment: Please, make sure you actually add the ip address, and not use the example ...

Comment: after creating /etc/docker/daemon.json docker service does not come up with "Start request repeated too quickly" error for some reason (I waited and rebooted machine, only removing daemon.json helped)

Comment: Thanks. This is the only answer docker successfully restart without rebooting machine.

Answer (score 24):

*For Windows users*

Add local registry here and apply:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

For Mac Users:
Update the docker preferences using the (docker) icon in top bar

Preferences -> Daemon -> Insecure Registry [Click (+) sign] -> add :port

hit "Apply & Restart" button at bottom

[image: Pic showing Docker preference window]

Answer (score 7):

I also had same issue and followed below steps:

**1. Create file**

```
 vi /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

**2. Add below content**

```
{
        "insecure-registries":["192.168.1.142:5000"]
 }
```

**3.Restart Docker**

```
service docker restart
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Windows and you get this error you need to create a file here: `"C:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json"`

and do the same as @Bspec mentioned above:

{ "insecure-registries":["myregistry.example.com:5000"] }

Then restart docker using PowerShell commands:

```
Stop-Service docker
Start-Service docker
```

Answer (score 2):

modifying "/etc/docker/daemon.json" didn't work for me.

Putting it under "/etc/sysconfig/docker" as below, worked.

INSECURE_REGISTRY="--insecure-registry 192.168.24.1:8787"

Comment: Thanks for showing us `--insecure-registry` option. In my case it was even another file `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker-options.conf` because I'm using Kubespray. So for others: you need to find your `DOCKER_OPTS` parameter. Just use this search: `grep -ER DOCKER_OPTS /etc` across `/etc` directory. In my specific case, to make settings effective I did: `systemctl daemon-reload`, `systemctl restart docker` and `ps -ef | grep dockerd` on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

In order **to push**, add the ip to insecure registry on the client side (e.g. for Windows)

[image]

**To pull**, add it to the server side (in this case Ubuntu)

```
vim /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

[image]

and then restart Docker.

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions worked on Ubuntu 18.04 so spend some time to find the root cause.

**Steps to solve an issue**

```
sudo vi /lib/systemd/system/docker.service
# ExecStart=dockerd .... --insecure-registry=192.168.99.100:5000
sudo systemctl stop docker.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start docker.service
```

---

**What was the issue?**

I would recommend to check where exactly `dockerd` options are configured regardless of you Linux distribution with:

```
sudo find /etc /lib -name 'docker*' | while read -r line; do grep dockerd $line /dev/null; done
```

Answer (score 0):

**first test localy**

```
docker push localhost:5000/<ImageName>
```

**if docker pushed is Done going to another server and do it:**

```
sudo nano /etc/docker/daemon.json


{"insecure-registries" : ["<HostName or IP Address registry server>:5000"]}
```

Saving and...

**and for next**

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo service docker restart
```

**nice!
now docker pushing on another server:**

```
docker tag <image id> <HostName or IP Address registry server>:5000/<ImageName>
docker push <HostName or IP Address registry server>:5000/<ImageName>
```

**Enjoy It.**