# Cannot push/pull to remote docker registry

Tags: linux, docker, boot2docker

I am trying to setup a repository within my network where others in the network can pull/push new docker images. I currently have a working docker registry running on a debian server with a front end (https://github.com/kwk/docker-registry-frontend); both are running on the same server.

- Debian Server is running 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2 (2017-03-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Most things seem to work...

1. **WORKS** - if i ssh into the server i can push/pull images to the registry
2. **WORKS** - from any other computer in the network i can access the front end and it properly displays the images in the registry.
3. **WORKS** - In a browser i can directly hit my.registry.ip:5000/v2/_catalog and i will get an array of image names that are stored in the registry.

But when i go to push/pull to the local registry...

1. **DOESN'T WORK** - Error response from daemon: no route to host

**Somethings to note:**

- I am using Windows and the docker terminal to try to push/pull images with registry.
- Version: 17.04.0-ce
- API Version: 1.28
- Docker Toolbox

We have also looked into numerous different posts and tried using the advice recommended in [Can not pull/push images after update docker to 1.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38695515/can-not-pull-push-images-after-update-docker-to-1-12) but it did not seem to remedy the issue. I am out of ideas on how to fix this. I believe i am very close and the fix is minor but i do not know where to go from here.

If you need anymore information please let me know!

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker Toolbox runs using a host on a VirtualBox VM. I would recommend spinning up a new VirtualBox VM on your machine. Can your curl my.registry.ip:5000/v2/_catalog from that VM? If not, networking issues with VirtualBox are likely the cause. If you are using a VPN, you will need to setup Bridged Networking to the Docker VM.

Comment: This was it! Thank you for the help :)